# How to use a custom object from a not accessible .jar

Tags: java, rapidminer

I have an .jar file that is used by a program, I want to write an extension for. One of my new methods requires a custom object from that jar.
If I import that custom class, I get an error because in eclipse the imported class and the required class seem to be different even if they have the same name.

Is it possible to use an object from a different project?

I can't import the jar because it's an extension. So it can be downloaded and used. I just want to extend this extension but I don't want to change the extension itself.
I've tried to cast the object but I get an error that it can't be casted.

Comment: Your question is very broad, so I fear there is no chance on getting a reasonable answer. If you want to write an extension for RapidMiner, please check the online guide here: https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/developers/extensions/
or check out the user community for detailed questions and answers from other devs and users:
https://community.rapidminer.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a classpath problem. Chances are that the original extension is in the classpath and again as part of your extension extension. For a class to be considered the same by the JVM, it must be in the same package, have the same name *and* be loaded by the same classloader. So a class loaded from your extension extension .jar is definitely considered different from any class of the same name loaded from the original extension .jar by another classloader, even if they are in fact bit-by-bit identical.

Comment: That's exactly what I asked for. So is there no other way? Is it possible to cast the "outer class" object to an "inner class" object?

Comment: No, that's not possible. For one, because to the JVM those two (identical) classes have nothing in common except `java.lang.Object` as root ancestor, and secondly because no piece of Java code can (statically) refer to *both* classes as would be needed for a cast from one type to the other. The only way to solve the issue is to have only one copy of the class file on the classpath. You could try and package/deploy your extension without the other extension's classes; if you're lucky, your code will at runtime refer to the classes already deployed in the other extension and everything is good.